# Передача поля/метода класса

Tags: c++

Существует класс **Realty** в котором экземпляры **Apartment** и вектор с объектами **catalog**. Метод **price_filter** должен  фильтровать объекты по переменной **price**. Как мне передать это поле каждого объекта для обработки в методе?

```
void price_filter()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < catalog.size(); i++)
    {
        if (//тут-> getPrice[i]// >= a && // и тут->  getPrice[i]// <= b)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

в джаве это выглядело бы следующим образом:

```
void price_filter(Realty o)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < catalog.size(); i++)
    {
        if (o.getPrice(i) >= a && o.getPrice(i) <= b)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка: Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3867    'Realty::getPrice': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member Buildings   F:\VS_Workspace\Buildings\Buildings\Buildings\Buildings.cpp 104

Весь код:

```
using namespace std;

class Realty
{
    string location;
    int area;
    int count_of_rooms;
    int price;
public:
    Realty(int area, int count_of_rooms, string location, int price)
    {
        this->area = area;
        this->count_of_rooms = count_of_rooms;
        this->location = location;
        this->price = price;
    }
    int getArea()
    {
        return area;
    }
    int getCount_of_rooms()
    {
        return count_of_rooms;
    }
    string getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }
    int getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
};
class Apartment : public Realty
{
    int floor;
    bool renovation;
public:
    Apartment(int floor, int area, int count_of_rooms, string location, bool renovation, int price) : Realty(area, count_of_rooms, location, price)
    {
        this->floor = floor;
        this->renovation = renovation;
    }

};

class Realtor
{

    std::vector <Realty*> catalog;
private:
    int a, b;

public:
    void setRange(int a, int b)
    {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }

    void add_realty(Realty* o)
    {
        catalog.push_back(o);
    };

    void price_filter(Realty o)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < catalog.size(); i++)
        {
            if (o.getPrice[i] >= a && o.getPrice[i] <= b)
            {
                //
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int enter;

    Realtor r;
    Apartment* ap1 = new Apartment(3, 400, 2, "Warszawa, Ursynów", true, 60000);
    Apartment* ap2 = new Apartment(3, 400, 2, "Warszawa, Ursynów", true, 100000);
    Apartment* ap3 = new Apartment(3, 400, 2, "Warszawa, Ursynów", true, 30000);
    Apartment* ap4 = new Apartment(3, 400, 2, "Warszawa, Ursynów", true, 70000);
    r.add_realty(ap1);

    cout << "Wybierz opcje" << endl; cin >> enter;
    if (enter == 1)
    {
        cout << "filter cen od i do " << endl;
        cout << "Wprowadz od" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        cout << "Wprowadz do" << endl;
        cin >> b;
        r.setRange(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что такое "поле каждого объекта"? Почему вы называете `price_filter` "методом"? Чей это метод? Какого класса? И почему вообще что-то куда-то нужно передавать?

Comment: price_filter - метод другого класса. Price - это переменная, которая существует у каждого объекта. Я хочу отфильтровать объекты по ней

Comment: Ну так сделайте как в Джаве и все.

Comment: информауия неполная

Comment: 1.как в джаве выдает ошибку, в описании она есть 
2. вектор в котором хранятся объекты

Comment: сейчас прикреплю весь код

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Во-первых, код вы привели фейковый: `int a, a;` - что это такое? Во-вторых, что это за синтаксис такой `getPrice(i)` и `getPrice[i]`? Что за мешанина из разных скобок? Вы нам будете рассказывать, что у вас и в Джаве так? Что такое вообще `getPrice(i)`? У метода `getPrice` нет параметров.

Comment: Всё исправил. Специально сидел и выписывал Вам левый код. Помочь не хотите? Как я понимаю метод getPrice возвращает значение. Вот оно мне и надо в этой функции

Comment: И плюсах и в джаве это бы выглядело не `o.getPrice[i]`, а `catalog[i].getPrice()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void price_filter()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < catalog.size(); i++)
    {
        if (catalog[i]->getPrice() && catalog[i]->getPrice() <= b)
        {
            // ....
        }
    }
}
```